# Отображение границ на листе Excel с использованием Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

подскажите пожалуйста имеется диапазон ячеек необходимо с использованием Apache POI отобразить все внутренние границы диапазона

```
CellRangeAddress region=new 
CellRangeAddress(7,9,0,4);
    RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM,region,sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM,region,sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM,region,sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM,region,sheet);
```

Приведенный код отображает внешние границы, а необходимо внутренние, знаю, что можно создать стиль для каждой ячейки диапазона и по всем пройтись, но думаю есть способ рациональнее. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел вот такое решение

```
PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate=new PropertyTemplate();
propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(7,9,0,4),
                BorderStyle.MEDIUM,BorderExtent.RIGHT);
propertyTemplate.applyBorders(sheet);
```

Вот ссылка на документацию:
[Javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/util/PropertyTemplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Единственный известный мне способ - создавать стили для каждой ячейки.

Но надо помнить, что у Workbook есть ограничения, накладываемые особенностями форматов XLS и XLSX. Например, стилей в XLSX не может быть больше 64000. А у версии 2003 года их вообще [допускалось только 4000](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel). Так же есть и [другие ограничения](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Office_2007).

То есть, идея такая - создать набор уникальных CellStyles, и потом переиспользовать их в разных ячейках.

```
CellStyle myCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
myCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
myCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
...
```

И дальше, когда создаёшь ячейки, просто переиспользуешь myCellStyle:

```
cell.setCellStyle(myCellStyle);
```

Куда интереснее то, как подбирать такие стили. Я не могу показать производственный код, но идея такая: создаётся кеш стилей (Map). Ключ формируется на основе всех значений стиля, которые могут различаться. Хотя бы так:

```
private String getCellStyleId() {
    return String.format("%s%s%s", fontName, fontHeightInPoints, fontColor);
}
```

Чтобы ключ не был слишком большим, можно поиграться с хэшами.

Далее всё просто. Строим ID стиля и ищем его в Map. Если есть - хорошо, берём существующий. В другом случае создаём и заносим в кеш. Удачи.

*С радостью выслушаю другие решения и комментарии.*